# How to validate select dropdown from custom payment method

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, validation

I have a custom payment method I've implemented and it has a form that looks something like this:

```
<div class="form-list" id="payment_form_<?php echo $this->getMethodCode() ?>" style="display:none;">
    <div>
        <label for="<?php echo $_code ?>_method_no"><?php echo $this->__('Method No') ?>*</label>
        <span>
          <select id="<?php echo $_code ?>_method_no" name="payment[method_no]"
                  class="dropdown validate-select payment-type-select"
                  value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getInfoData('method_no')) ?>">
              <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('--Please Select--') ?></option>
              <option title="<?php echo $this->__('Method One') ?>" value="1">Method One</option>
              <option title="<?php echo $this->__('Method Two') ?>" value="2">Method Two</option>
              <option title="<?php echo $this->__('Method Three') ?>" value="3">Method Three</option>
          </select>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <?php echo $this->getMethod()->getConfigData('message'); ?>
</div>
```

My question is, how do I validate this in my  model validate function?  I know that I have validation on the front end with the class `validate-select` but I would like to know how I can check the value in the validate function.  I have something like this right now but it is not working:

```
<?php
class Name_Mypaymentmethod_Model_Standard extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract {
    protected $_code = 'mypaymentmethod';

    protected $_isInitializeNeeded      = true;
    protected $_canUseInternal          = true;
    protected $_canUseForMultishipping  = false;

    protected $_formBlockType = 'mypaymentmethod/form';
    protected $_infoBlockType = 'mypaymentmethod/info';

    public function getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl() {
        return Mage::getUrl('mypaymentmethod/payment/redirect', array('_secure' => true));
    }

    public function assignData($data) {
        $info = $this->getInfoInstance();

        if ($data->getMethodNo())
        {
          $info->setMethodNo($data->getMethodNo());
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function validate() {
        parent::validate();
        $info = $this->getInfoInstance();

        if (!$info->getMethodNo())
        {
          $errorCode = 'invalid_data';
          $errorMsg = $this->_getHelper()->__("Please select a method.\n");
        }

        if ($errorMsg) 
        {
          Mage::throwException($errorMsg);
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
?>
```

It seems like the `$info->getMethodNo()` function is not working for my select dropdown.  How do I get the value?  I've been looking through forums, tutorials, posts for the last couple hours and can't find anything that shows validating a select dropdown like this.

Any help would be appreciated!  Thanks

Comment: Can you please update the answer and add the full code of the class where the validate() method is declared?

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau updated the question

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Magento regular one page checkout:

1. Your form comes to the `Mage_Checkout_OnepageController::savePaymentAction()` method.
2. Then data are transferred to model:

   ```
   $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('payment', array());
   $result = $this->getOnepage()->savePayment($data);
   ```

   If you don't see your data at this stage, look for a problem on frontend (form submit).
3. Then your data are transferred to your payment method in the `Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage::savePayment()`:

   ```
   $payment = $quote->getPayment();
   $payment->importData($data);
   $quote->save();
   ```
4. Validation happens in the `importData()` method (`Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Payment::importData()`):

   ```
   /**
    * Import data array to payment method object,
    * Method calls quote totals collect because payment method availability
    * can be related to quote totals
    *
    * @param   array $data
    * @throws  Mage_Core_Exception
    * @return  Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Payment
    */
   public function importData(array $data)
   {
       $data = new Varien_Object($data);
       Mage::dispatchEvent(
           $this->_eventPrefix . '_import_data_before',
           array(
               $this->_eventObject=>$this,
               'input'=>$data,
           )
       );

       $this->setMethod($data->getMethod());
       $method = $this->getMethodInstance();

       /**
        * Payment availability related with quote totals.
        * We have to recollect quote totals before checking
        */
       $this->getQuote()->collectTotals();

       if (!$method->isAvailable($this->getQuote())
           || !$method->isApplicableToQuote($this->getQuote(), $data->getChecks())
       ) {
           Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('sales')->__('The requested Payment Method is not available.'));
       }

       $method->assignData($data);
       /*
       * validating the payment data
       */
       $method->validate();
       return $this;
   }
   ```

   If on this step data exist at the beginning, but are absent at the end, that possibly a problem in one of observers (`$this->_eventPrefix . '_import_data_before'`).

You need to check your data on each of these steps.
I hope this information will be useful for you.